# Sharepoint online parts catalog

Tags: wss-3.0

I have a client looking for an online catalog of for parts inventory that end users can view.  Does anyone have any examples that they may have developed in the past?

Answer (score 1):

What works for one customer would be totally different than another and probably proprietary.  Do you have some specific requirements?  Something can be modeled and mocked up fairly quickly.